# Subset sum decision problem -- how to verify "false" case in polynomial time?

Tags: complexity-theory, theory, subset-sum

I'm having a bit of trouble understanding how one would verify if there is no solution to a given instance of the subset sum problem in polynomial time.

Of course you could easily verify the positive case: simply provide the list of integers which add up to the target sum and check they are all in the original set. (O(N))

How do you verify that the answer "false" is the correct one in polynomial time?

Comment: If you could do this then you could answer the decision problem in polynomial time by trying to verify that the answer is false, and if the verification fails then the answer must be true. So what makes you think this is possible?

Comment: I'm clearly very confused :)

Comment: Perhaps your confusion is about the definition of NP: quoting Wikipedia, *"NP is the set of decision problems for which the problem instances, where the answer is "yes", have proofs verifiable in polynomial time"*. There is no requirement that there is a proof verifiable in polynomial time when the answer is "no". https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP_(complexity)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s actually not known how to do this - and indeed it’s conjectured that it’s not possible to do so!

The class NP consists of problems where “yes” instances can be verified in polynomial time. The subset sum problem is a canonical example of a problem in NP. Importantly, notice that the definition of NP says nothing about what happens if the answer is “no” - maybe it’ll be easy to show this, or maybe there isn’t an efficient algorithm for doing so.

A counterpart to NP is the class co-NP, which consists of problems where “no” instances can be verified in polynomial time. A canonical example of such a problem is the tautology problem - given a propositional logic formula, is it always true regardless of what values the variables are given? If the formula isn’t a tautology, it’s easy to verify this by having someone tell you how to assign the values to the variables such that the formula is false. But if the formula is always true, it’s unclear how you’d show this efficiently.

Just as the P = NP problem hasn’t been solved, the NP = co-NP problem is also open. We don’t know whether problems where “yes” answers have fast verification are the same as problems where “no” answers have fast verification.

What we do know is that if any NP-complete problem is in co-NP, then NP = co-NP. And since subset sum is NP-complete, there’s no known polynomial time algorithm to verify if the answer to a subset sum instance is “no.”